# Party betrayal in an evil campaign

Tags: dnd-5e, evil-campaign

I am participating in a once/twice a week 5e campaign based on running around doing conventionally evil things.  The DM and I have talked and decided that I will be the BBEG. (Working against the party from within)

I am playing a half elf Druid. My subclass is [Circle of the Shifter](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/210110/Circle-of-the-Shifter--Druid-5e), a homebrew subclass found on DMs Guild that allows you to change aspects of yourself rather than the character's whole body.

- The other PCs are a Tabaxi rogue and another Tabaxi Monk (way of the shadow) and neither of them really like the RP part of dnd and are really there for the killing and stealing whereas my goal is to have fun both with RPing and with the combat

The plan is for me to work against them from within until they catch me, at which point we will battle and I will either kill them or run away and become an NPC under the DM's control.

What methods would be best to weaken the other players secretly without directly attacking or otherwise revealing myself to them?

Comment: Hey Alphadog, welcome to rpg.se.  You might want to take the [tour].  You might want to be a little clearer about your character and your motivation.  I started to answer this question and found I couldn't really.  It might not be possible for us to tell you how to trick people in your game, other than "don't get caught".  It might even really just be opinion-based.  Does looking at the definitions of the alignments clarify things for you?  Also, "shady" is pretty context-driven.

Comment: It will help to get the second player's class included.

Comment: *An Aside:* While you and the DM okay with your PC being the campaign's bad guy, are the other players? This is the kind of thing that can burn folks on RPGs forever. Of course, it's also the kind of thing that can make some folks *love* RPGs forever. Anyway, if the DM hasn't already, it may be wise for him to get the group together and broach the idea: *Wouldn't it be cool if one of you were the Big Bad?* Then gauge the other players' reactions. Just test the waters a bit is all.